# Trying to loop through firebase and display each object as a card React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, jsx

My data is structured like so
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWsr3.png

I am trying to loop through the database and put the data from each card into props for my ProductCard> component. It takes in values as 
I've been racking my brain with this and googling constantly, but this is my best attempt.

```js
const db = getDatabase();
const dbRef = ref(db, 'products');
onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      return (
          <ProductCard title={childSnapshot.val().prod_title} />
      )
    });
  }, {
    onlyOnce: true
  });
```

I'm very much a noob with react so I appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` function instead of `forEach` to return an array of JSX elements, and then do something with this elements array (not sure what, since your snippet is too small):

```
const elements = snapshot.map((childSnapshot) => {
  return (
      <ProductCard title={childSnapshot.val().prod_title} />
  )
});
// do something with elements array here or maybe just return it
```